# Gradle action order

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm confuse about gradle action order.
Here is my task below:

```
task myTask6 {
   description "Here's a task with a configuration block"
   group "Some group"
   doLast {
       println "5"
   }
   println "2"
   leftShift { println "4" }
   doFirst {
       println "3"
   }
}
myTask6 << { println "1" }
```

In my opinion,the result should be:
1
2
3
4
5
But the result is:
2
3
5
1

What happened?
`leftShift` could be assigned with a closure right? Because `myTask6.leftShift = {}` is correct.

Comment: If any of the answers solves the problem or was useful please upvote/accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation is quite easy. At first [configuration phase](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:configuration_and_execution_phase) lines are executed so **2** will be printed. Then all the actions added via (`doLast`, `doFirst`, `<<`) are executed in order they were added. So **3 5 1** will be the output. `doFirst` adds an action to the beginning of the list while `doLast`, `leftShift` to the end.

Now, what's the problem with:

```
leftShift { println "4" }
```

?

The problem lies in the fact that both [`Closure`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#leftShift(groovy.lang.Closure)) and [`Task`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#leftShift(groovy.lang.Closure)) have `leftShift` defined and even though a task instance is set as delegate and `DELEGATE_FIRST` resolution strategy is used when calling the configuration closure (by configuration closure I mean the big closure that is passed just after *myTask6* literal) the `Closure`'s `leftShift` will be called. To fix the problem you need to explicitly define which `leftShift` you need to call:

```
task myTask6 {
   description "Here's a task with a configuration block"
   group "Some group"
   doLast {
       println "5"
   }
   println "2"
   it.leftShift { println "4" }
   doFirst {
       println "3"
   }
}
myTask6 << { println "1" }
```

or

```
task myTask6 { t ->
   description "Here's a task with a configuration block"
   group "Some group"
   doLast {
       println "5"
   }
   println "2"
   t.leftShift { println "4" }
   doFirst {
       println "3"
   }
}
myTask6 << { println "1" }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's a awesome answer!

Answer (score 0):

`println "2"` executed in the configuration phase.

And, Next is execution phase doFirst.

```
   doFirst{
       println "3"
   }
```

And <<{} is just `doLast` alias.
So  `println "5"` is first.

Comment: Thank you very mush.  I got another question: Why didn't leftShift {println "4"} exec? Because leftShift can only be used by myTask6.leftShift ??

Comment: Yes.  [Task:leftShift](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#org.gradle.api.Task:leftShift(groovy.lang.Closure)) and [Closure:leftShift](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Closure.html#leftShift(groovy.lang.Closure)) are differ.